# ASP.NET Pass Parameters between WebForms

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

I am creating a Application with Login credentials (username and password). All the user accounts will be stored in the SQL Table.

I cannot use Sessions/QueryString to pass values between the pages and I have multiple forms for users to enter data.

What is the best method so that I can control and make sure that the user is logged in and transfer whether the login is correct and transfer the login ids between forms securely.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Security is _hard_.  Do not re-invent the wheel.  You should use ASP.Net's built-in membership system.

Comment: Its the same application. All the usernames are supposed to be saved in the SL tables. Not allowed to use sessions/cookies at all :(. Is there any other method other than Server.Transfer....

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to pass is ID then go for cookies

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cannot use cookies, Sessions nor querystring. Is there any other way to ways I can achieve the goal?

Comment: not sure why you can't use any of the above, that's just weird :S

Comment: Anyways, I don't think there is a built in way for that

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other path that I can follow?